# How do I stack multiple frequency tables into one table in R?

Tags: r, frequency

I don't know if I am using the wrong terminology in trying to search for an answer to my problem, but I have been unable to figure out what seems to be a simple issue. I have a large data set with multiple variables that I want to run a series of 2-way frequency tables on. One of my variables is "Country" and I need to divide up my frequencies by each country (of which there are 31). I have 3 variables, Protest, Riot, and a combination of the two - Demonstrations. I am doing a crosstabs with each of these to a lagged data panel variable - lag.value. I understand how to code them as independent tests, but, is there a way to "stack" everything together in one table? As in lag.value is on the top, and each row represents a countries output? or to selective make a list of several countries for the test?

```
DT <- data.table(Country = rep(c("India", "Pakistan", "Sudan"), 12), 
             Protest = sample( 0:1, size = 12, replace = T),
             Riot = sample( 0:1, size = 12, replace = T), 
             Demonstrations = sample( 0:1, size = 12, replace = T),
             lag.value = sample( 0:1, size = 12, replace = T))

DT[Country == 'India', table(Protest, lag.value)]
DT[Country == 'Pakistan', table(Protest, lag.value)]
DT[Country == 'Sudan', table(Protest, lag.value)]
```

Looking at just the protest to lag.value... what I understand how to do are individual tables

```
#india
# lag.value
#Protest 0 1
#      0 3 3
#      1 3 3

#pakistan
# lag.value
#Protest 0 1
#      1 3 9

#sudan
#lag.value
#Protest 0 1
#      0 3 3
#      1 6 0
```

Is there a way to make one clean table (with country names) showing? something like this:

```
#         lag value
#Protest     0 1 
# India    0 3 3
#          1 3 3
# Pakistan 1 3 9 
# Sudan    0 3 3
#          1 6 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running separate `table` on each subset, do an `ftable` by including the 'Country' column as well

```
DT[, ftable(Country, Protest, lag.value)]
          lag.value  0  1
Country  Protest                
India    0                  0  6
         1                  0  6
Pakistan 0                  0  9
         1                  3  0
Sudan    0                  0  0
         1                  0 12
```